# Python: How can I know which package I am importing?

Tags: python, ipython

I would like to have this info during run-time or in ipython. For example,

```
import matplotlib
```

How do I know which matplotlib.py is used if I have multiple versions or I just want to know where the file located.

Thanks

Comment: I think you actually want to look for `__version__`, but I don't know if it's defined for matplotlib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspect the module's `__file__` attribute.

```
In [1]: import matplotlib

In [2]: matplotlib.__file__
Out[2]: '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.pyc'
```

(Works in vanilla Python too.)

Comment: You can even just type `matplotlib`, giving you `<module 'matplotlib' from '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.pyc'>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sys.modules` to find the path of it.

Such as:

```
import math
import sys
print sys.modules['math']
```